# How to "skip" first response with python requests.get

Tags: python, http, python-requests

i want to automatically get some information off a website *target.url*
when i open it in the browser a short loading screen shows up and then the information is displayed.

So when i use

```
resp = reqeusts.get(target.url)
write_to_disk(resp.text)
```

i only get the loading screen animation since its the first response to an http request to this site.

Is there a way to "skip" this response or to establish a connection and send multiple requests via this connection? I tried several things but none of them worked for me :)

Comment: Check what happens in the [network activity](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/devtools/network/) screen, copy the CURL request of the target page and [convert](https://curl.trillworks.com/) it to python code.

Comment: it also depends if the loading screen is a html page which forwards to something else, or an iframe replaced by something, an embedded div etc. It really depends how the web page is implemented

Comment: I think the problem is that the whole thing is a dashboard which uses javascript to load several things, do you think its possible to get this via the same method you suggested?

Comment: Also the loading screen does not forward to anything it gets replaced by the other content

Comment: Yeah, may well be able to get the information by finding the relevant URL in the "network activity" screen; it'll probably even be in JSON format, which will be easier to interpret than the eventual HTML, just the relevant numbers and other information with no extraneous formatting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use selenium.
Just access the webpage. Wait for a few (milli)seconds (until desired content is loaded) and then get the HTML from the selenium driver.